# с++ помогите с формулой произведения

Tags: c++, ряды

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>


int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "rus");
    int r;
    float x;
    float sum = 1;
    printf("Введите число");
    scanf_s("%d", &r);
    scanf_s("%f", &x);
    for (int n=0; n<=r; n++)
    {
        sum = sum * (1 + ((pow(-1, n - 1)*pow(x, 2 * n)) / ((n + 2)*(n + 1))));
    }
    printf("%f", sum);
}
```

[image: Задание]

P.S Неправильно подсчитывает

Comment: Неправильно считает ...

Comment: если считает неверно, тогда предоставьте набор входных данных и ожидаемый результат.

Comment: Автор, дай комментарий, что было не так с твоим кодом?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот функция, которая для данных `x` и `k` вычисляет произведение:

```
double Prod(double x, unsigned int k)
{
    double p = 0.5, term = -0.5; // Значение для n==0
    x *= x;
    for(unsigned int n = 1; n <= k; ++n)
        p *= 1 + (term *= -x*n/(n+2));
    return p;
}
```

Ну, а вставить ее в нужное место в программу - это вы уж сами должны сообразить :)

Comment: Ну-ну, который минус поставил - где ошибка? Или просто кто-то С/С++ не знает и ответ не понял :)

Comment: @vp_arth Потому что тогда надо будет подставлять, образно говоря, в `term` значение для `n == -1`. У меня расчет построен на отношении двух членов, а не вычислении абсолютного значения члена. Если я начну цикл с 0, значит, чтобы использовать формулу, надо член для `n==-1`. Сами, надеюсь, видите неприятность? Нет, конечно, если хочется через 3 вызова `pow`, то флаг в руки, но если хочется быстро и точно...

Comment: я сравнил ответы, которые выдают обе программы) и они похоже совпадают. А так как автор сказал, что программа выше "считает неверно", то и эта считает неверно. Но это мелось Сам код плох  для учеников.

Comment: @KoVadim Надеюсь, вы сами можете написать свой код и проверить правильность ответов. Что до начинающего... Если вы в самом начале не вдолбите начинающему, что `pow` - это уже если все остальное не работает, то...  И как такие вещи надо считать быстро и эффективно. Вот и будем получать и дальше Гугль-программистов... :) Если препод не из идиотов, то обязан был разбирать такие вещи. В мое время численные методы читали математики, а не, пардон, говнокодеры...

Comment: я написал свой код также. и он выдает такой же результат. pow - это нормально, если только нет требования рекуррентности.

Comment: @KoVadim `pow` - это для вычисления (-1)^n НЕНОРМАЛЬНО! Так же, как ненормально считать факториал там, где его не надо считать. Как и возводить x в степень 2n через pow, имея x^(2n-2). Как ненормально применять алгоритм O(n^3) там, где можно применить O(log n). **ПИСАТЬ НЕЭФФЕКТИВНО - НЕНОРМАЛЬНО**

Comment: минус один в степени можно и через модуль вычислить. Но есть правило - вначале получи правильный результат, а потом уже делай эффективно

Comment: Получи так, что **исправить** будет нельзя, а только писать заново? :) Знаете, от кого-кого, но от вас всего написанного выше - не ожидал... :(

Comment: KoVadim прав, особенно в учебных целях - сначала надо научиться писать хоть как. Оптимизации - это потом. А то что вы бросаетесь оптимизировать то что не работает (или неясно как работает) - это скорее к вам упрек..

Comment: что бы понять, что такое оптимально, вначале нужно написать хоть как то. Есть видео от Кейт Грегори, где она говорит, что ее пригласили помочь человеку с оптимизацией кода. Человек долго объяснял, как он хочет оптимизировать и где слабые места. Но на контрольный вопрос " а код хоть компилируется", получил ответ "нет, но это не важно":)

Comment: Ну, честно говоря, Harry ничего не оптимизировал. Он просто решил задачу так, как привык =)

Comment: мне лично не нравится код, который Harry привел как решение. оно ужасное. и для студентов, и для продакшн кода. (если что, минус я не ставил)

Comment: @KoVadim, а в чём конкретно вы видите проблему? В том, что мутацию term стоит вынести в отдельный стейтмент? Рекуррентное соотношение верное, как его по другому задать-то?

Comment: рекуррентное соотношение нормальное. А вот "мутация term" - ну не нужно так. Плюс магические константы предвычисленных значений.