# c++ сумма бесконечных рядов с заданной точностью

Tags: c++, ряды

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>


int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "rus");
    int i = 1;
    float sum = 0;
    float e;
    int a = 0;
    scanf_s("%f", &e);
    while (abs(a) >= e)
    {
        a = (pow(-1,i) / pow(3, i) + pow(4, i));
        sum += a;
        i++;
    }
    printf("Сумма равна(c точностью) = %f", sum);
```

Что не так с кодом? Почему неправильно работает?[image: Задание]

Comment: А где вы взяли `(-1)**i`?

Answer (score 1):

**ошибка 1:**

```
int a = 0;
scanf_s("%f", &e);
while (abs(a) >= e)
```

а вам не кажется, что если e ввели ненулевое, то `while` вообще работать не будет?

лучше уж используйте `do while` или `for` без условия выхода (условие внутри цикла делать будете)

**ошибка 2**

```
a = (pow(-1,i) / pow(3, i) + pow(4, i));
```

это совершенно не та формула, которая у вас на картинке

у вас некорректно расставлены скобки.

я уже молчу про то, что `-1` в формуле и не пахнет

Comment: А вас целочисленность `a` не смущает?

Comment: @Harry, проглядел, теперь смущает, хотя целочисленное все таки работать будет- результат будет далек от правды правда :)

Answer (score 1):

Сейчас меня [заминусуют](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1206841/195342), но не могу молчать :)

Начнем с того, что у вас

```
int a = 0;
```

Ну как можно явно дробные члены хранить в целочисленном значении? Вы же начинаете нули суммировать...

Далее, формула не та, но даже если бы она была та... Ну не нужен здесь `pow`! И даже `i` не требуется :) Вот правильное решение:

```
double Sum(double eps)
{
    double sum = 0.0;
    for(double three = 1, four = 1, term = 2*eps /* :) */; term >= eps;)
    {
        three *= 3;
        four  *= 4;
        term = 1/(three + four);
        sum += term;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: @vp_arth О, это уже я туплю - показалось, что с нуля. Спасибо за замечание, исправляю.

Answer (score 0):

Считает неправильно потому, что вы считаете не по той формуле, которую привели. В строке:

```
a = (pow(-1,i) / pow(3, i) + pow(4, i));
```

Нужно правильно расставить скобки:

```
a = pow(-1,i) / (pow(3, i) + pow(4, i));
```

Comment: А вас целочисленность `a` не смущает?

Comment: @Harry, да действительно, сразу не обратил внимания.